# captcha on quick questions?

Tags: feature-request, captcha

Sometimes i come to the site to ask 2 or 3 question quickly, maybe edit a post or two, etc.
Its not uncommon for a captcha to appear for me. in fact it often does (typically when i leave and need to finish a post and i take to long).

I like to request adding logic to not captcha me if i ask 2 quick question but to allow me 2 or 3 quick questions in the span of a 2 mins. Then display a captcha if i am trying to post an unreasonably much in the span of a few mins. I think 3 per 3 mins is fair and maybe 5 question every 15 mins should keep most spam away.

-back button- i just had a captcha come up now! and i didnt take long and i think i only posted 3 answers (superuser, on a one feature per post thread) in the last 15 mins!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seriously? You need to ask 3 questions in 3 minutes? Put some thought and effort into your questions. It should take *at least* a few minutes per question.

Captcha's are designed to prevent users from spamming, and they're doing their job. If 2-3 questions in 2-3 minutes *isn't* spam, then what is? 5 questions per minute? The cutoff has to be reasonable. A captcha takes only a few seconds to fill out, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: easy. i may have two questions that are basic like is there a pair class in C# and how to iterator keys and get their value. Alternatively i can ask a question, google something, post and ask another based on what i googled. Or i could just have a similar question to one that i posted but still different enough to warrant another post. Besides capctha arent going to prevent a user from spamming, they will prevent bots from spamming and AFAIK SO have things to prevent bots from spamming (other then captcha on post).

Comment: Yup, you're completely right. I apologize.

Comment: :               )