# Captcha is a little draconian on here

Tags: support, captcha

I've been asked it three times today which is bordering on annoying. Last instance was trying to post with a new tag (not allowed to do that) so I removed it and hit post again. Bang - unreadable captcha prompt.

Cheers, Rob.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2085 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9464 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2236 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1343 - the last one's by far the most informative.

Comment: Also, if the CAPTCHA is unreadable, are you a cyborg?

Comment: Actually, couple of times I have felt that typos were also accepted on the CAPTCHA (meaning, I mistyped one character and found it passed me). I am annoyed; that confuses the cybernetic brain ;P

Comment: Nice to know I'm not alone. BTW - why isn't there a meta.serverfault.com? :-) I knew about meta but assumed it was stackoverflow only.

Comment: Saying duplicate might be recursive

Comment: @nik: Recaptcha uses one known word and one unknown word. So long as you type the known one in correctly, you're let in. The unknown word is used to help hone OCR technology.

Comment: There is a meta.serverfault.com:
http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/14267/

Comment: You were wrong with the "a little".

Answer (score 2):

for unreadable captcha's, click the button with arrows, looks like a refresh... It'll get you a new image to decode.

You don't have it near as bad as I do.  Virtually every submit I do on META has to be validated because of Google's jQuery files getting blocked by FinJin.

Comment: Hmm, just annoying new users isn't the best idea: "Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because: •new users can only post answers every 3 minutes; try again later.". Personally, I can answer a simple question faster than that :-)

Comment: Y make user have to type captchas again and again is this a game or what