# Add Skeptics.SE to data.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

Now that it has graduated, @waffles suggested that it would be possible to get Skeptics.SE added to [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) if I asked nicely.

Pretty please, with sugar on top?

Comment: It should happen as a matter of course in the next data update.

Comment: @ChrisF: That's what I had originally thought, but he muttered something about being a manual task that he needed to do.

Comment: I was thinking that "matter of course" was "site graduates -> Sam gets notified -> Sam adds site to data dump", but I suppose the assumption that Sam gets notified was rather a big one :)

Comment: @ChrisF: Maybe if we tag this [waffles]? (we actually have a meta tag) ;-)

Comment: @Ajax If it's really a major bug, you don't need to worry about "community abuse".

Comment: @John it can really be abused to a point that it could harm any SE site so badly it would take days to recover

Comment: @Ajax I see. It would appear I misunderstood your terminology. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already done a few weeks ago :) https://data.stackexchange.com/skeptics/queries

Comment: @ajax333221 there is an email address at the footer of each page on the site

Comment: I gave up and was going to post it, but the bug [was already found](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46671/captcha-bypass)