# Question claims stack capcha can be bypassed trivially. 

Tags: support, captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Captcha Bypass](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46671/captcha-bypass)

[This question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30717/attention-it-is-possible-to-bypass-the-captcha-on-webmasters-stackexchange) was posted to webmaster pro a short while ago:

> Maybe this is pointless or maybe you people already are aware, but I
>   just wanted to let you know. Delete the message if it is unfitting or
>   to not spread this information.
>
> When posting a question, fill out all the field and click the post
>   button When reaching the captcha page, go back Submit post again This
>   is how this post was done.

Re-posted here for a heads up to the admins.

Comment: (As an aside: you know there's [a delete option for comments](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mzmLE.png)?)