# It is possible to bypass the captcha on stackexchange sites

Tags: bug, captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Captcha Bypass](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46671/captcha-bypass)

Maybe this is pointless or maybe you people already are aware, but I just wanted to let you know. Delete the message if it is unfitting or to not spread this information.

1. When posting a question, fill out all the field and click the post button
2. When reaching the captcha page, go back
3. Submit post again

Confirmed as working on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Post made this way: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30717/attention-it-is-possible-to-bypass-the-captcha-on-webmasters-stackexchange

Comment: Somewhat confusingly, the person who suggested that you post this here (which was the correct thing to do), also [posted it themselves](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135097).

Comment: TO WHOM THIS MAY CONCERN: You could just use a normal title. The ATTENTION is unnecessary.